# Is it possible to run commandLine in gradle with bash -c?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a task in a build.gradle file, in which I'd like to run this command:

`(export ENV_VAR=/my/path ; /path/to/build.sh)`

I tried running this in gradle:

```
task myTask {
   doLast {
      exec {
        commandLine ['bash', '-c', '"(export ENV_VAR=/my/path ; /path/to/build.sh)"']
      }
   }
}
```

Unfortunately, I have an error that says

```
Successfully started process 'command 'bash''
bash: (export ENV_VAR=/my/path ; /path/to/build.sh): No such file or directory
```

Now I'm sure the file exists and the specified paths are correct. Running this command manually in the terminal works.

Is there something in gradle that makes a `bash -c` like this not work? I can't think of another way to make an export like this otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Try without the extra quotes:

```
commandLine ['bash', '-c', '(export ENV_VAR=/my/path ; /path/to/build.sh)']
```

When you run that in the command line, your shell needs the quotes to pass to the command (which happens to be bash) as a single argument, but gradle is already doing that with that syntax, so bash is receiving literally one argument `"(export ENV_VAR=/my/path ; /path/to/build.sh)"` and since it does not recognize this as internal syntax, tries to run a command with this name.